# How to parse this Json Data in Swift and Save Offline

Tags: json, swift3

```
{
     "Name": "Abc",
     "Detail": [
         {
             "Phone": "0123456789",
             "Tid": 0,
             "Gid": 4
         },
         {
             "Phone": "0123456789",
             "Tid": 0,
             "Gid": 4
         },
         {
             "Phone": "0123456789",
             "Tid": 0,
             "Gid": 4
         },
         {
             "Phone": "0123456789",
             "Tid": 0,
             "Gid": 4
         }
     ],
     "Email": "asdd"
 }
```

I want to show `Name` on ViewController and show `Detail` on Next DetailView Controller.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In viewController1

Convert Downloaded Data to Dictionary format using JSONSerialization

```
  do {
     //Converting data to Dictionary
     let result : NSDictionary! = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

      } catch let error {
       // error
       print("URL: \(url) error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
```

retrive your value of "name" like

```
let nameValue = result.value(forKey: "name") as! String // name value
nameLabel.text = nameValue
```

Show your name nameValue in ViewController1

Pass your Detail value like

```
let details = result.value(forKey: "Detail") as! [[:]]

let detailVC = DetailViewController()
detailVC.details = details // Pass your detail values from ViewController1 to DetailViewController
```

show your detail values in DetailViewController

```
print(details)

for detail in details {
  // retrive all values in loop
  let phone = detail.value(forKey: "Phone") as! String
  let tid = detail.value(forKey: "Tid") as! Int
  let gid = detail.value(forKey: "Gid") as! Int

  print("phone: \(phone), tid: \(tid), gid: \(gid)") // print values
}
```

Comment: Don't suggest `NSDictionary / NSArray` in Swift, don't suggest `mutableContainers` in Swift – by the way assigning `mutableContainers` to an immutable dictionary is nonsense anyway – , don't suggest `valueForKey` in Swift. It's all very bad habit.

Comment: i want to save this locally like whatsapp. Tell me please

Comment: Use any thing like Userdefault, CoreData, plist, temp file to save data